# io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: A session is either terminated or not started

Tags: appium, rpa, uipath

I am trying to integrate appium with UiPath to automate an application.
I have configured the appium server and started the session, and the application is opening on the virtual device via appium.

However, when i try to link the device in Uipath, i am failing and unable to pass the mobile device manager stage. I have added the device, but when i click on the run button, it fails and the error "io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: A session is either terminated or not started" is thrown multiple times in the appium server logs.

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

P.S screenshots:-
[Mobile device manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnha8.png)

[appium logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/684ej.png)

[session capabilities tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UirSO.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Appium 1.20 then Appium 1.20 has some issues,
so try Appium 1.21.0 or an older version of Appium.

This actually solves same error for me.